# Parsing json using DeSerialization in C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm getting this `"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary 2[System.String,System.Object]" is not of type "MyCustomControl.Result" and cannot be used in this generic collection`error while parsing json using `jvascripSerializer().DeSerialize`, my types look like below

```
class templateResponse
{
    public String multicast_id;
    public String success;
    public String failure;
    public String canonical_ids;
    public Results results
}
public class Result
{
    public String message_id;
    public String registration_id;
    public String error;
}
Public class Results : ObservableCollection<Result>
{

}
```

My json data look like below,

```
{"\"multicast_id\":7400896764380883211,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1351777805148960%39895cf0f9fd7ecd\"}]}"
```

This is my parsing code of json data

```
templateResponse result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<templateResponse>(json);
```

Please help me to overcome this error and tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: That json string is not properly formatted json (missing starting bracket). Is it a copy paste error?

Comment: @Jite I have updated the correct json string but still i got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The json data contains int-type values, but your c# class contains string values.
Try to change them to their right type.
Im not sure how strict the JavaScriptSerializer is, but this could be a issue.

Also try set Results to be a List, might work better, this cause the Result in the json is an array of objects, not a key-value collection of objects.

Like:

```
class templateResponse
{
    public int multicast_id;
    public int success;
    public int failure;
    public int canonical_ids;
    public List<Result> results
}
public class Result
{
    public string message_id;
    public string registration_id;
    public string error;
}
```

Comment: Re-read your code, will edit my answer, check again in a min.

Comment: Yeah, i already tried using list but i don't want to use list in the type.

Comment: Then i think you will need to change the data type in the json to be a key-value collection instead of an array.

Comment: `results : { "one": { "message_id": "id" }, "two":  { "message_id": "id2" } }` will be treated as a key-value collection when converted (like a Dictionary<string, result>).
While `"results": [{object}, {object}]` will be treated as a list (List<result>).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your JSON string to deserialize using  `Newtonsoft.Json` and it succedded
gives following output

```
  string json = "{\"multicast_id\":7400896764380883211,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1351777805148960%39895cf0f9fd7ecd\"}]}";
  var expectedresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
   "multicast_id":7400896764380883211,
   "success":1,
   "failure":0,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[
      {
         "message_id":"0:1351777805148960%39895cf0f9fd7ecd"
      }
   ]
}
```

for more information visit http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: How to parse this json using JavascriptSerializer. I don't want to use any other third party control.

Comment: I tried using `JavascriptSerializer` and it succeedd only change was instead of `public Results results` i have use  `public List<Result> results`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it fails is because you expose the Results-collection. The built-in serializer can't handle properties that are inherited from a generic list. Don't ask me why, but I read somewhere that you should not expose classes inherited from List, it is not intended for that.

I made a (quite ugly) workaround where I implemented a custom JavaScriptConverter to handle my object. Basically you inherit from System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptConverter, implement the abstract classes and then add it to your web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization>
                <converters>
                    <add name="MyJsonConverter" type="corp.com.MyJsonConverter" />
                </converters>
            </jsonSerialization>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Here is a link to the official docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.100).aspx